# Importing MYSQL database to NeO4j

Tags: mysql, csv, graph, neo4j, foreign-key-relationship

I have a mysql database on a remote server which I am trying to migrate into Neo4j database. For this I dumped the individual tables into csv files and am now planning to use the LOAD CSV functionality to create graphs from the tables.

How does loading each table preserve the relationship between tables?
In other words, how can I generate a graph for the entire database and not just a single table?

Comment: See [this page](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-importing-data-and-etl/#_northwind_introduction) for an example of how to import the Northwind dataset into Neo4j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Load each table as a CSV
2. Create indexes on your relationship field (Neo4j only does single property indexes)
3. Use MATCH() to locate related records between the tables
4. Use MERGE(a)-[:RELATIONSHIP]->(b) to create the relationship between the tables.

Run "all at once", this'll create a large transaction, won't go to completion, and most likely will crash with a heap error. Getting around that issue will require loading the CSV first, then creating the relationships in batches of 10K-100K transaction blocks.

One way to accomplish that goal is:

```
MATCH (a:LabelA)
MATCH (b:LabelB {id: a.id}) WHERE NOT (a)-[:RELATIONSHIP]->(b)
WITH a, b LIMIT 50000
MERGE (a)-[:RELATIONSHIP]->(b)
```

What this does is find :LabelB records that don't have a relationship with the :LabelA records and then creates that relationship for the first 50,000 records it finds. Running this repeatedly will eventually create all the relationships you want.

Comment: Thanks Tim, how do you keep the data in sync after this initial import?

Comment: You'll have to dump deltas, do a full dump and refresh the db, or change the application to update the graph db when it updates the sql db.